# Dockerコンテナ上のMySQLにタイムゾーンの設定を反映するには？

Tags: mysql, docker

MySQLのタイムゾーン設定について質問があります。
下記のDockerfileを使用し、ビルド、ランするとコンテナがエラーを出力しexitしてしまいます。

mysql_tzinfo_to_sqlコマンドでtime zoneのテーブル情報をロードするような
方法を試しましたが、解消しません（さらに元々読み込まれているようでした）。

ご教授いただければと思います。

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN { \
    echo '[mysqld]'; \
    echo 'default-time-zone = "Asia/Tokyo"'; \
} > /etc/mysql/conf.d/timezome.cnf
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのタイムゾーンテーブルに`Asia/Tokyo`というタイムゾーンが存在しないのだと思います。

一般的に`mysql-tzinfo-to-sql`を使ってロードするためのSQLを作成して、`mysql`でロードします。
[MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 4.4.6 mysql_tzinfo_to_sql — タイムゾーンテーブルのロード](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html)

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

私はやったことがありませんが、Dockerでやる場合の例が、本家Stackoverflowにありました。ご参考まで。
[Configure time zone to mysql docker container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959601/configure-time-zone-to-mysql-docker-container)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。また、返信が遅れてしまいすいません。mysqlアプリケーションの初期化処理のあとにタイムゾーンテーブルにデータが書き込まれているのでしょうか。